# cross referencing libraries and linking in C

Tags: c, linker, libraries, cross-reference

I have two C static libraries `libA` and `libB` that I link against my executable `E`.

`libA` has a function that makes a call to a function that is in `libB`:

```
myLibAFunctionThatCallsAfunctionInLibB( ... )
{ libB_function(...); }
```

Both libraries compile fine. My executable `E` also compiles fine. `E` is compiled with gcc using `-lA -lB` flags with the proper `-I` and `-L` paths.

The problem occurs at runtime when `myLibAFunctionThatCallsAfunctionInLibB` is called. I get the following error:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _libB_function
  Referenced from: libA.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

I have checked that all architectures are the same (i386). Also `nm -a libB.a` shows that `libB_function` is actually part of `libB`. I have tried declaring `libB_function(...);` as `extern` in `libA` with no difference. I am using gcc 4.2.1 on osx 10.6 if that's of any incidence.

Is it just not possible to cross reference libraries the way I am trying to do it? Do I HAVE to include the implementation code for `libB_function` in my `libA` library?

Thanks

Baba

Comment: can you show the output of `ldd <your exec>`

Comment: Are both libraries static (`.a`)? Or is one of them shared/dynamic?

Comment: @ larsman Actually one library is dynamic .dylib and the other is static .a

Comment: @ SB ldd does not exist on darwin. I tried otool -L but it seems to only be showing the dynamically loaded libraries not the static ones. In any case nm -a E shows that the libB_function is part of the executable E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I found a work around. I rewrote my function in libB instead of libA. In short I now call libA from libB instead of libB from libA. In this case it works. I guess it has to do with the fact that libA is dynamic loaded library and B is static ... but I do not understand why. Any expert light is welcomed.

Thanks.